# Scraping with javascript pagination

Tags: web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a website with multiple pages and the pagination is done with javascript.
The webpage is the following: https://www.camara.cl/legislacion/ProyectosDeLey/tramitacion.aspx?prmID=8355&prmBOLETIN=7958-05

The webpage is only an example. The same pagination is used on the webpage to display all bills proposed for legislation, list which will be ultimately scraped.

Using the developer tools in Chrome and examining the network activity, I can't find the parameters being send when clicking on a page number. The javascript being used for the pagination seems to be this one (cbpHorizontalMenu.js): https://gist.github.com/sunmughan/6b912927d2fe8c854b2d67825940ee6c

I'm trying to do the scraping in R, but I'm open to other programming languages or programs (script running in Chrome, Python, Puppeteer, Phantomjs).

Answer (score 0):

It's an ASP form with event validation using some hidden value in the inputs inside the form. The steps you can take is :

- execute a GET on your target URL
- extract the form element with id `form1`
- extract all input name/value inside the form
- extract how many page there are (how many `a` links in the `div` with class `paginacion`) (only the first time)
- build the `__EVENTTARGET` field value iterating over the page `ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$pager$rptPager$ctl{PAGE_NUMBER}$page`
- execute a POST on the same URL with the fields extracted before as form data parameters
- execute the same as before until you have all the pages

The following is an example in [python](/questions/tagged/python) that use requests and beautifulsoup. The data is appended to a [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) dataframe :

```python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.camara.cl/legislacion/ProyectosDeLey/tramitacion.aspx"
query_params = {
    "prmID":"8355",
    "prmBOLETIN":"7958-05"
}
data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Fecha','Sesión','Etapa','Sub-etapa','Documento'])

def process(r, page_index):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    #get the form
    form = soup.find("form", {"id": "form1"})
    #get all the input values
    payload = dict([(t["name"],t["value"]) for t in form.findAll("input")])

    #append to the existing data
    global data
    data = data.append(pd.read_html(r.text)[0], ignore_index=True)

    #page number (necessary for the first request)
    page_num = len(soup.find("div",{"class":"paginacion"}).findAll("a"))

    #build the target value for the next page
    next_page_str = str(page_index+1).zfill(2)
    payload["__EVENTTARGET"] = f'ctl00$ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContentPlaceHolder1$pager$rptPager$ctl{next_page_str}$page'

    return { "page_num": page_num, "payload": payload}

r = requests.get(url, params= query_params)

result = process(r, 1)
page_num = result["page_num"]

for i in range(0, page_num):
    r = requests.post( url,params = query_params, data = result["payload"])
    print(f'process page{i + 2}')
    result = process(r, i + 2)

print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Puppeteer and the idea is to just click on `span.actual + a` until its not there anymore:

```js
while(await page.$('span.actual + a')){
  await page.click('span.actual + a')
  // do something with page here
}
```